# Row position in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tried this code

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["NRType"].ToString() == "0002")
{
    ReportObj.ReportFileName = "report1.rpt";
}
else if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["NRType"].ToString() == "0011")
{
    ReportObj.ReportFileName = "report2.rpt";
}
else if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["NRType"].ToString() == "0007")
{
    ReportObj.ReportFileName = "report3.rpt";
}
```

This is the function where I get the data and I call a stored procedure

```
public DataSet getreport()
{
    DataSet ds;
    try
    {
        SqlParameter[] Params = 
        { 
            new SqlParameter("@FormID",SqlDbType.VarChar),
        };
        if (FormID != null)
        {
            Params[0].Value = FormID;
        }
        else
        {
            Params[0].Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        ds = GetDataSet("SP_GetCertReportData", Params);
        return ds;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and there is error occurred

> "There is no row at position 0"

Any solutions?

Comment: You have no data in your first table.. The error tells you directly. Can you investigate/show us the code you're using to populate the table?

Comment: please check update question

Comment: Then your stored procedure is probably returning no rows. You'll need to simply debug this.. The error is correct, your assumptions are incorrect - you need to walk through the code with a debugger to find out why you don't have any information (or even check your stored procedure).

Comment: the store procedure return rows.. i have several data in grid view .. when i click on second last record it shows data but when i click on first record it shows this error

Comment: What do you mean "click on first record"? Where are you clicking? And may we know exactly what is supposed to happen on that click?

Comment: there is button in gridview

Answer (score 2):

I see a few things I would change. First, I would check that the table count is > 0. Then check that table [0] != null. Then row count is > 0 and it is != null. If these checks pass, then you know you are into the right table and into the right row, and you have to deal with the columns.

The next thing I see is that you are calling your columns on the same line as the row, which typically is not a problem, but when you are trying to debug a "no row at position 0", you have to back out as much as possible and make sure everything is correct. Magic strings ["NRType"] may not be named correctly either. Once you get into the debugger, use your Immediate Window at your breakpoint to test for what is wrong.

If you need more info, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0] != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    var table = ds.Tables[0];
    var row = table.Rows[0];
    var value = row["NRType"] + "";
    if (value == "0002")
    {
        ReportObj.ReportFileName = "report1.rpt";
    }
    else if (value == "0011")
    {
        ReportObj.ReportFileName = "report2.rpt";
    }
    else if (value == "0007")
    {
        ReportObj.ReportFileName = "report3.rpt";
    }
}
```

Please note instead of `row["NRType"].ToString()`, I have used `row["NRType"] + ""`. Because attempting `row["NRType"].ToString()` can cause an exception if `row["NRType"]` value is null but `row["NRType"] + ""` never throws an exception, instead it will return an empty string if the value is null. But if you still want to use `ToString()` then it will add one more step and that is to check if the value is not null:

```
if(row["NRType"]!=null && row["NRType"].ToString() == "002"){
    //your code
}
```